3M Intake System Cleaner Sold Without Applicator
I purchased this product based on brand name (3M) and after watching the video available as part of the offer attachments, but for some reason didn't bother checking out reviews.  I am sure it is a good product, but, per all 1-star reviews posted, it comes withont the means to actually apply it as demonstrated in the video...hard to believe.
So...question: does anyone have a suggestion, other than buying what is apparently a hard to find and expensive application kit, as to how this product might actually be used as intended?  For the most part this means how might one attach something, and what, to spray outlet.
3M-08958-Intake-System-Cleaner on Amazon

Just forget it.  I've used Berryman's Intake Valve and Combustion Chamber Cleaner, with excellent results.  It has a fool-proof delivery system and is easy to use.  If you'd like more cleaning of the intake specifically, use BG Intake Cleaner.  In any case, follow-up with a few tankfuls of BG 44k to clean any remaining carbon you force down between the piston rings, because it's the only product that really works.
You can get more out of any of these products by spraying a few ounces of Marvel Mystery Oil through the intake at high idle, then let the car sit overnight.  It softens all the deposits through-and-through for better cleaning.

Thanks for the comprehensive response.  Q re: Marvel Mystery Oil...you mention spraying, but it appears to only come as an additive, i.e. liquid, for oil and gasoline?  Am I missing a specific version that come as a spray, or do you mean put it in a spray bottle and apply, or something else?

Also, do you see a particular difference between MMO and other similar products like Lucas Oil or Seafoam gas/oil additives?

I mean put the MMO in a spray bottle.  I've used Seafoam and it's great for light deposits, but MMO is better for stubborn deposits because it's a bit heavier.  Lucas Oil is too heavy, creating it's own deposits when burned at low speeds which have to be removed by lighter solvents.  Afterwards, remember to change the oil and use BG 44k in the gas tank to avoid loosened deposits accumulating in piston rings.
